# What does the {???} mean in the VC++ Watch window?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, watch

I am debugging a C project with Visual Studio 2013. What does the `{???}` mean in the below `Watch` window?

[image]

I guess there must be something wrong and I searched a bit. But no luck.

Comment: The value that the pointer points to would normally be shown there, but since the pointer is null, it can't be dereferenced and the value cannot be obtained. `???` signifies that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igor’s suggestion is correct, this is the sample for this issue.

If I disable the line code “currnode->nextnode = NULL;”, it will show the same result as yours.

[image]

But if I enable it, it would show the NULL value like this screen shot, so it would be related to null value of the pointer.
[image]