# Changing numeral system from hex to dec in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, data-structures, visual-studio-2015

I've been recently writing implementation of heap, and I found out that my IDE during debugging displays key values in hex. I tried to change to decimal, by unchecking "display in hex" in autos/locals window, changing from hex to signed/unsigned in memory windows and passing ",d" after my variable name in watch window, but none of them works. I've defined my node like this:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int *a;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    char *b;
}tree;
```

and any pointer in locals window displays like that:

```
p   0x00db4570 {a=0x00000000 {???} left=0x00db45b0 {a=0x00000043 {???} left=0x00dbbc88 {a=0x00000767 {???} ...} ...} ...}
```

I only want to have "`a`" values in decimal.

Thanks for any help and suggestions and sorry for my english.

Comment: Displaying pointers as decimal is uncommon. The tacit assumption is that anyone interested in the value of a pointer will be able to read hexadecimal.

Comment: Try to watch `*(p->a)`.

Comment: Does not work ( "<Unable to read memory>" ).

Comment: @ BlackHawk, could you share a complete sample here? So we could repro this issue in our side? In addition, it seems that it showed "???" value in your side, like this case I met here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841021/what-does-the-mean-in-the-vc-watch-window, please check that whether you give the value of the pointer.